# How do I transition these Python codes to rstudio?

Tags: python, r

For one of my classes I have to code a problem in both R and Python, the only issue is that sometimes the instructions given only apply to the Python code like this question: Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done". Once "done" is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

```
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: bad data
Invalid input
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: done
16 3 5.333333333333333
```

R doesn't have an except function only a try which makes transitioning this code hard. Here is what I have so far in rstudio:

```
{
  num=0
  total=0
  while(number<-readline(promp=('Enter number here: '))){
    if(number == 'done'){
      break
    }
    try(num1<-as.numeric(number))
    print(paste('Invalid Input'))
    num<-num+1
    total<-total+num1
  print(paste(total,num,total/num))
  }
}
```

The error message I keep getting is: `Error in while (number <- readline(promp = ("Enter number here: "))) { : argument is not interpretable as logical` Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what the code in the question seems to want.

```
num <- 0
total <- 0
repeat{
  number <- readline(promp = 'Enter number here: ')
  if(number == 'done'){
    break
  }
  num1 <- tryCatch(as.numeric(number),
                   warning = function(w) w)
  if(inherits(num1, 'warning')){
    print('Invalid Input')
  } else {
    num <- num + 1
    total <- total + num1
    cat(total, num, total/num, '\n')
  }
}
```

---

## Edit

In the answer above I had misread the specification on printing the values *only at the end*, the following code only prints the total, the count and the average at the end.

```
num <- NULL
repeat{
  number <- readline(promp = 'Enter number here: ')
  if(number == 'done'){
    break
  }
  num1 <- tryCatch(as.numeric(number),
                   warning = function(w) w)
  if(inherits(num1, 'warning')){
    print('Invalid Input')
  } else {
    num <- c(num1, num)
  }
}
Enter number here: 4
Enter number here: 5
Enter number here: bad data
[1] "Invalid Input"
Enter number here: 7
Enter number here: done

c(total = sum(num), count = length(num), avg = mean(num))
    total     count       avg 
16.000000  3.000000  5.333333
```

Note that now the vector `num` holds all numbers entered at the keyboard and that the functions `max`, `min`, etc, can be used on it.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never thought to use warning or inherits.

Comment: @hayden123 `tryCatch` is more flaxible than `try`, it also has a `error = function(e) etc` that can later be tested with `inherits(., "error")`.